# Azure AD OpenId connect integration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm currently integration azure ad for OIDC on java application, I am using MSAL4J https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j and following sample provided by Microsoft:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample

I just want OpenID connect for authentication and do not want accessToken. for my use case id_token should be enough

May I know if I have to explicitly validate the signature, I see Msal4j does not validate the signing signatures.

Please let me know if validating id_token is secure process to login the user.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended for web applications ("confidential client applications") to validate the `id token`, but there is no hard requirement for "how much" you should validate. If your web application receives the token over an https connection from your Identity Provider, then you are relatively safe. At the very least though (after validating the signature -more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-the-signature)), you should validate the `aud` and `nonce` claims, which represents the intended recipient of the token and whether the token is being replayed, respectively. More details in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#validating-an-id_token).

EDIT: corrected statement regarding whether MSAL4J validates tokens.

Comment: In my scenario I do not need access_token as I'm implementing OIDC only for authentication and Id_token should be enough. I do not see MSAL4J Validating id_token. Could you please guide me if you have looked into the code?

Comment: @Har my sincerest apologies. I've checked and indeed, MSAL4J does not validate tokens (in fact, none of the MSAL libraries do that, except in .NET where ASP.NET Core middleware does that validation). You should check the Java sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp). Token validation is shown in [this part](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/blob/54b385853939a2f5e230e2cb0629f7f5a7253a52/msal-java-webapp-sample/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/msalwebsample/AuthHelper.java#L67).